# MYSQL order by case, column order

Tags: mysql, laravel

Sorry for english.

I have in my database a column called "order_news", and I'm trying to display the data according to the order.

example data:

```
------------------------
id | title    | order_news
-------------------------
1  | news 1   | 0
--------------------------
2  | news 2   | 1
--------------------------
3  | news 3   | 2
---------------------------
4  | news 4   | 3
-------------------------
```

my code, i am using Laravel:

```
News::orderByRaw(
        "
        CASE 
         WHEN order_news = 1 THEN 1
         WHEN order_news = 2 THEN 2
         WHEN order_news = 3 THEN 3

         WHEN order_news = 0 THEN 1
         WHEN order_news = 0 THEN 2
         WHEN order_news = 0 THEN 3
       END
        DESC,
       created_at DESC
       "
     )
   ->take(3)
   ->get();
```

ok. if position 1, 2, 3 does not exist. Position 0 occupy the missing place.

example:

1. if 1 no exit = 0-2-3 (news 1, news 3 and news 4)
2. if 2 no exit = 1-0-3 (news 2, news 1 and news 4)
3. if 3 no exit = 1-2-0 (news 2, news 3 and news 1)

With my code, 1. and 2. work but 3. returned 1-0-2 and i want 1-2-0.
Can help me? tnx.

Comment: Please post your entire query and some sample data. It's very hard to tell what you're asking here.

Comment: Please rephrase your question, provide some sample data and expected output.

Comment: @EdCottrell I have edited a bit, now do you understand?

Answer (score 1):

As a starting point, a `CASE` with multiple `WHEN`s for the same condition (`WHEN order_news = 0 THEN ...`) doesn't make much sense; only one of them will be used.

In fact, the `WHEN order_news = 0 ...` expressions are what causes the issue here. When you retrieve the items with `title`s `news 2`, `news 3`, and `news 1`, here's what you get:

```
title    order_news   your order clause            your order value
news 2   1            WHEN order_news = 1 THEN 1   1
news 3   2            WHEN order_news = 2 THEN 2   2
news 1   0            WHEN order_news = 0 THEN 1   1
```

Because `news 2` and `news 1` get the same order value (`1`), they both come before `news 3`. So, you get `order_news` values of `1-0-2`, not `1-2-0`.

It's not clear from your question exactly what you want, but it's clear that your current `CASE` statement won't get you there. To get around that, just rank by `order_news` or don't set an explicit ordering at all. Your current `CASE` statement is already a mess, and it's not scalable.